# Laravel 4 migrate:rollback with --path on artisan CLI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having some roadblock on Laravel 4.

Since I can't make `artisan:migrate` generate migrations from inner folders of `app/database/migrations` *(ex: app/database/migrations/app1)*

I have this on my custom command `app:migrate`

```
/* default path */
$this->call('migrate'); 

/* custom path */
$this->call('migrate', array('--path' => 'app/database/migrations/app1'));
```

but i also want an `app:refresh` command which will rollback all the migrations from the custom path then from the default path.. then re migrate and seed everything just like what `migrate:refresh --seed` does

how do i reverse this? calling:

```
$this->call('migrate:rollback', array('--path' => 'app/database/migrations/app1'));
```

will produce an error saying

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The "--path" option does not exist.
```

can somebody help please.

thanks!

Comment: Well, atm, there is really no way. Only the actual file name is stored on the database, without its path and there is no path parameter for the rollback command. You could, of course, implement it the parameter, but that would be bad when you happen to have ran migrations from multiple paths. The best would probably find a way to store in the DB where that came from, fork the repo and propose the change.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is make sure your migration classes can be autoloaded. The easiest way to do so is to add the path to the folder you're keeping them to `composer.json`'s `autoload.classmap`:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "app/database/migrations/app1",
    ]
},
```

Answer (score -2):

You should re-run migrate with "--path" option manually for this case.

Comment: would that drop the old tables, re-insert them and re-seed them again?

Comment: I've checked and yes, they do not remove the old data from the DB before you seed again..