# How to call ...blade.php in different folder inside views folder in laravel

Tags: php, html, web, laravel-5, netbeans

Excuse me, i would like to ask about how to call another page blade in different subfolder inside views.
Example :

```
views
   --home(subfolder)
   --beranda(subfolder)
       --refresh.blade.php
   --layouts(subfolder)
       --master.blade.php
```

in master.blade.php implements template page, when i click one link in this folder may have to go in refresh.blade.php.
Likely another web layout, they have a lot of link in header like 'Home', 'Paper', etc.

I'm still learned more about laravel as beginner practice.
May you can help me, i'll appreciate that.

Regard, Aga.

Comment: Further reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473978/laravel-5-keep-views-and-models-in-separate-folder-in-resources-views-directory?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, it really help me... i just confused how to explain what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer to some directives such as `@include` and `@extends` in the laravel blade.

For example, in the `admin.common.header` view (located at admin/common/header.blade.php), we have some basic page code (common to various pages such as navigation bar or layout). We use `@yield` such as `@yield ("extra_js")` or `@yield ("extra_css")` where we want to add code later.

header.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        something maybe ...
        @yield("extra_css")
    </head>
    <body>
        something maybe ...
        @yield("extra_js")
    </body>
</html>
```

And in another view such as `admin.feedback.feedback`, you can use `@extends('admin.common.header')` at the top of the code to inheritance the template and you will get the layout of this template.
For different content in the feedback template, you can use `@section` to give you code to fill in the inheritance template such as `@section('extra_js')`.

feedback.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.common.header')
@section('extra_js')
<script> something... </script>
@endsection
```

If you want to include one blade, just use `@include`.

```
<div>
    @include('shared.errors')

    <form>
        <!-- Form Contents -->
    </form>
</div>
```

In laravel blade there are many instructions to complete the rendering of the template, if you want to know clearly, please refer to the corresponding version of the [official document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade).

Comment: code is successful but the view of this link is under the contents of the file in the click