# how to make a directory in controller - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a `Panel` directory inside `Controller` directory .

[image]

there is a `login` function inside `AdminController.php`

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    //


    public function login()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

in `routes.php` I wrote a route like this:

```
Route::get('/cp/login','Panel\AdminController@login');
```

but when I run below url I got some errors that there isn't exist this controller :

http://localhost:8000/cp/login

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 280: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\Panel\AdminController does not exist

Comment: It could be that laravel hasn't updated autoloder. Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: try to set your controller namespace to App\Http\Controllers\Panel

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850542/laravel-controller-subfolder-routing   check this you will get your solution

Comment: @Pardeep Pathania I used `dump-autoload` but doesn't  work

Comment: @Bindesh Pandya now I get this error : `FatalErrorException in AdminController.php line 10: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Panel\Controller' not found`

Comment: did u check the link i have sent to you?

Comment: I have seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the appropriate namespace to the top of the `AdminController` file, you will also need to specify the namespace for the `Controller` class that it extends, as they are under different sub-namespaces.

You can read more about PSR-4 autoloading here http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/.

Based on the directory structure that you have there it should read

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class AdminController extends Controller {

        //..

    }
```

Comment: your answer true but u must add this line : `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Answer (score 1):

you should add the namespace to the contorller

Change you namespace to

**namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel;**

Laravel will resolve controllers based on your name spacing, not on your directory structure.