# laravel can't find controller in subfolder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm trying to put the HomeController in a folder called Front. This is Laravel 5.6

So the path to my controller is Controllers/Front/HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
    {
```

Then in my routes I have this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

As suggested in this Stackoverflow: [Laravel Controller Subfolder routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850542/laravel-controller-subfolder-routing) I have tried to add the controller to the subfolder, then run composer dump-autoload yet it doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may have to run `composer dumpautoload`. If you moved the file and/or changed the namespace, that could be an issue in your composer.lock file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add all route in group and make prefix for it

```
  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Front'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Either specify the prefix in the controller string: `'Front\HomeController@index'` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#controllers-and-namespaces)

Or put your route in a group with the namespace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51800675/7362396 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-namespaces)

Comment: In another project i have there was no need to add the Front\ in the routes, also laravel 5.6

Comment: Maybe there you had the namespace prefix specified in a route group? That is also a viable option. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-namespaces