# How to register api on the routes of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have question regarding registering the api on the route.php
I got an error accessing my api that I already created on the route.php

> Class App\Http\Controllers/api/UserController does not exist

I create api folder I named it as **api** inside Controllers/api I create UserController.php

**My Function:**

```
public function index() {

    $table_slider = DB::select('SELECT content_id,link,file,slider_sorting,content_pages FROM content_structure as cs LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid,file FROM content_upload_assets) cua ON cs.content_id = cua.cid WHERE content_pages = ? AND cs.status = ? ORDER BY content_id DESC ',[

        'Slider',
        'Active'

    ]);
    return response()->json($table_slider);
}
```

On my api.php

```
Route::get('index','/api/UserController@index');
```

To solved the issue I used this route.

Route::get('index','api\UserController@index')

Comment: Did you declare UserController as a class? Something like `class UserController extends Controller`?

Comment: @AlchemistShahed yes alchemist, its default declared when creating controller

Answer (score 3):

I think you should double check your api route. As per my understanding your route declaration should be corrected as follows.

```
Route::get('index','\api\UserController@index');
```

Here is more related topic to refer.[Laravel Controller Subfolder routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850542/laravel-controller-subfolder-routing)

Think this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong directory separator:

```
Route::get('index','/api/UserController@index')
```

Change it to

```
Route::get('index','\api\UserController@index')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong way to point the controller, You can change your route like this:

```
Route::get('index','api\UserController@index');
```

A much better way is using namespace. Your controller should look like,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\api;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

    $table_slider = DB::select('SELECT content_id,link,file,slider_sorting,content_pages FROM content_structure as cs LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid,file FROM content_upload_assets) cua ON cs.content_id = cua.cid WHERE content_pages = ? AND cs.status = ? ORDER BY content_id DESC ',[

    'Slider',
    'Active'

    ]);

    return response()->json($table_slider);
}
```

Now, you can specify namespace along with route as:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'api'],function(){
    Route::get('index','UserController@index');
});
```

If any confusion feel free to ask.

Comment: After that i got this error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\api\DB' not found

Comment: add the following line at the top `use DB;`